# Why is awk printing chinese looking characters

Tags: windows, awk

I've never had anything like this in all the years I've used AWK.
I've tried both gawk and mawk.

I've cut my awk script down to

```
 { print }
```

Should just echo every line. But every other line is printed as if it is on a different code page.

Files are created by exporting from Access, thusly:

```
Dim oApplication
Set oApplication = CreateObject("Access.Application")
oApplication.OpenAccessProject sFileName
For Each myObj In oApplication.CurrentProject.AllForms
    WScript.Echo "Exporting FORM " & myObj.FullName
    oApplication.SaveAsText acForm, myObj.FullName, sExportpath & "\" & myObj.FullName & ".form"
    oApplication.DoCmd.Close acForm, myObj.FullName
    dctDelete.Add "FO" & myObj.FullName, acForm
Next
```

Resulting source files look like

```
Operation =1
Option =0
Begin InputTables
    Name ="Fee Types"
End
Begin OutputColumns
    Expression ="[Fee Types].ID"
    Expression ="[Fee Types].Type"
    Expression ="[Fee Types].Category"
End
```

Output looks like

```
Operation =1
਍伀瀀琀椀漀渀 㴀　ഀഀ
Begin InputTables
਍    一愀洀攀 㴀∀䘀攀攀 吀礀瀀攀猀∀ഀഀ
End
਍䈀攀最椀渀 伀甀琀瀀甀琀䌀漀氀甀洀渀猀ഀഀ
    Expression ="[Fee Types].ID"
਍    䔀砀瀀爀攀猀猀椀漀渀 㴀∀嬀䘀攀攀 吀礀瀀攀猀崀⸀吀礀瀀攀∀ഀഀ
    Expression ="[Fee Types].Category"
਍䔀渀搀ഀഀ
਍
```

Executed with

```
 gawk.exe -f "FilterBinary.awk"  input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/yhfMMP_jx-Q

Comment: Is there any chance that there are two files named FilterBinary.awk?  Are you running a CYGWIN bash shell or Windows cmd shell?  Is the shell variable AWKPATH set?  What is TERM set to?

Comment: @KenJackson Two files: Unlikely as changes to this script are reflected in the output.  Windows command shell. TERM and AWKPATH are not set.

Comment: `gawk.exe "{print}" input.txt`  This command avoids reading the program file and writes the output directly to the terminal.  Worth a try since this is so very odd.  You could also try gawk.exe v3.1.6 here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that the file is UTF-16LE encoded with CRLF but was saved into a git repo with `text eol=crlf`. The file is already corrupted, and you'll have to uncorrupt it before you can process it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I followed your steps and I got the same output and input:

```
Operation =1
Option =0
Begin InputTables
    Name ="Fee Types"
End
Begin OutputColumns
    Expression ="[Fee Types].ID"
    Expression ="[Fee Types].Type"
    Expression ="[Fee Types].Category"
End
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still the weirdest thing I've ever seen.
Printing the ordinal value of every character showed that there was a literal null between every visible character and a couple with values of 254 and 255.

No idea why that only played havoc with every other line.
But it does explain why none of my matching was working.

Obviously, the solution was to filter it and only print characters with Ord values of 13, or above 31 and below 128.

Comment: That is not weird. That is UTF-16LE encoding. The 254 and 255 are the UTF-16LE BOM.

Comment: Perhaps the proper question is, how do I get AWK  to read it and write it back out? As it stands,  AWK pattern matching doesn't work without filtering the intervening null bytes out first.

Comment: Go back to the source and save the file as UTF8 instead of UTF16.

Comment: @RaymondChen I updated the question to include the origin of the files. I agree that it is probably a code page issue, but I'm still puzzled by why it wouldn't print all the lines the same. Why half the lines in ascii and half in characters?

Comment: The files are corrupted. I can't find `Access.Application.SaveAsText`; the closest are [`SaveAsTemplate` and `SaveAsAXL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application). If you can convince SaveAsText to save them as UTF-8 or even ASCII that would fix the problem. The problem affects every other line because somebody is injecting a single 0x0D byte at each line terminator, and since UTF-16LE uses pairs of bytes to represent characters, adding a single byte shifts the pairing, and adding a second one shifts it back.